# Change cursor in file type input

Tags: html, css, html-input

I have an `input` element for file uploading (type='file'). I'm trying to put some style in it and it almost works. I just can't get to change the cursor to a `pointer` when hover over the image. It only appears when the cursor is over the bottom of the image.

```css
div.wrapper{
  position:relative;
     height: 40px;
}
div.upload {position:absolute;
     background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Momentum_GlossyEntireSet/32/folder_open-add.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
 }
div.upload input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#fileDesc{
  top:10px;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:0px;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;      
  font-size:18px;
  color:#3383bb;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="upload">
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="uploader"><span id="fileDesc">No file selected...</span>
  </div>
</div>
<input id="parseXml" type="button" value="Load file" onClick="parseXml()" style="vertical-align: top" />
```

Comment: what about this https://jsfiddle.net/detst0kc/ ???

Comment: I may was unclear from my question, I want the image of the folder to have a pointer cursor. In my code it does but (for uknown reason) only over the bottom half of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Below code might help

```
   <div class="wrapper">
     <input type="file" name="photo" id="uploader-photo" />
     <label for="uploader-photo"></label>
     <label class="nostyle">No file selected...</label>
    </div>   

    label {
         cursor: pointer;
         width: 50px;
         height: 40px;
         display: inline-block;
         background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Momentum_GlossyEntireSet/32/folder_open-add.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
    label.nostyle {
        background: none;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: initial;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: top;
    }    
    #uploader-photo {
       opacity: 0;
       position: absolute;
       z-index: -1;
    }
```

Comment: Yeap, that definately pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.wrapper{
  position:relative;
     height: 40px;
}
div.upload {position:absolute;
     background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Momentum_GlossyEntireSet/32/folder_open-add.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
 }
div.upload input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
}
div.upload {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#fileDesc{
  top:10px;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:0px;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;      
  font-size:18px;
  color:#3383bb;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="upload">
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="uploader"><span id="fileDesc">No file selected...</span>
  </div>
</div>
<input id="parseXml" type="button" value="Load file" onClick="parseXml()" style="vertical-align: top" />
```

Comment: Cursor doesn't change to pointer when hovering over the image.

Answer (score 0):

**These css changes above make the label also clickable.**

```
div.upload input {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-right: 200px;

}

#fileDesc {
    top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #3383bb;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```css
div.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}
div.upload {
  position: absolute;
  background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Momentum_GlossyEntireSet/32/folder_open-add.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
div.upload input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 200px;
}
#fileDesc {
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #3383bb;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="upload">
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="uploader"><span id="fileDesc">No file selected...</span>
  </div>
</div>
<input id="parseXml" type="button" value="Load file" onClick="parseXml()" style="vertical-align: top" />
```

Comment: Still, cursor doesn't change to pointer when hovering over the top half of the image, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following css to your existing code. This will get the job done.

```
div.upload input {
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: -100px;}
```